# Отловить внезапное завершение программы

Tags: java, swing

Мне необходимо отловить снятие программы с выполнения как это сделать?
Событие `windowDeactivated` срабатывает не только в случае непредвиденного заверешния программы, но и в случае корректного завершения программы. Можно как-то отловить код, с которым завершилась программа? 
Допустим мне нужен

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: это код возврата, его можно узнать по месту запуска, например если это bat или sh файл - присвоить его в переменную

Comment: а можно тогда как-то по-другому отлавливать состояние, когда программу сняли с выполнения и логировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть возможность повесить ShutdownHook, он сработает при штатном завершении, например при`ctrl+c` в консоли:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() { 
        System.out.println("hook");
    }
});
```

но в случае с каким нибудь `kill -9` и он не придет.

Comment: Тогда получается, что необходимо написать ещё 1 программу "монитор", которая будет отслеживать состояние этой программы и дописывать лог если что? И если да, то как можно что-то подобное реализовать?

Comment: эта программа - скрипт операционной системы, sh, bat И так далее, для этого и есть код возврата

Comment: Можно какую-нибудь ссылочку на эту тему?

Comment: @i_burykin я пропусти Ваше последнее сообщение про ссылку, Вам еще нужна доп информация?

Comment: да, если можно.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы очевидно, если программа завершилась, то она уже ничего логировать не может.

Comment: Тогда получается, что необходимо написать ещё 1 программу "монитор", которая будет отслеживать состояние этой программы и дописывать лог если что? И если да, то как можно что-то подобное реализовать?

Comment: @i_burykin, а что пользователю помешает и её прибить? Или прибить обе одновременно? Ты что-то сомнительное делаешь...

Comment: Мне по заданию надо такое сделать... поэтому и ищу способы отлавливания завершения программы и логгирования этого момента